# Unselectable scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

When a scrollable container is an `a` tag with a `href` attribute the scrollbar cannot be selected instead the whole container drags. This only occurs in **Firefox**. Edge, Chrome & IE11 seem okay.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Demo CSS */
  background: #ddd;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Demo CSS */
h3 {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}
h4 {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 15px 20px 15px 0px;
}
* {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!-- Demo HTML: -->
<p>
  When a scrollable container is an <code>&lt;a&gt;</code> tag with a <code>href</code> attribute then the scrollbar cannot be selected. Instead the whole container drags. This only occurs in <strong>Firefox</strong>. Edge, Chrome & IE11 seem okay.
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Note: </strong>Using the mouse wheel to scroll still works.
</p>
<h4>href="#"</h4>
<h4><small>href="javascript:void(0);"</small></h4>
<h4>No href</h4>
<br clear="all" />
<!-- Buggy HTML: -->
<a href="#">
  <div>
    <div>Row 1</div>
    <div>Row 2</div>
    <div>Row 3</div>
    <div>Row 4</div>
    <div>Row 5</div>
    <div>Row 6</div>
    <div>Row 7</div>
    <div>Row 8</div>
    <div>Row 9</div>
    <div>Row 10</div>
    <div>Row 11</div>
    <div>Row 12</div>
    <div>Row 13</div>
    <div>Row 14</div>
    <div>Row 15</div>
    <div>Row 16</div>
    <div>Row 17</div>
    <div>Row 18</div>
    <div>Row 19</div>
    <div>Row 20</div>
    <div>Row 21</div>
    <div>Row 22</div>
    <div>Row 23</div>
    <div>Row 24</div>
    <div>Row 25</div>
    <div>Row 26</div>
    <div>Row 27</div>
    <div>Row 28</div>
    <div>Row 29</div>
    <div>Row 30</div>
    <div>Row 31</div>
    <div>Row 32</div>
    <div>Row 33</div>
    <div>Row 34</div>
    <div>Row 35</div>
    <div>Row 36</div>
    <div>Row 37</div>
    <div>Row 38</div>
    <div>Row 39</div>
    <div>Row 40</div>
    <div>Row 41</div>
    <div>Row 42</div>
    <div>Row 43</div>
    <div>Row 44</div>
    <div>Row 45</div>
    <div>Row 46</div>
    <div>Row 47</div>
    <div>Row 48</div>
    <div>Row 49</div>
    <div>Row 50</div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
  <div>
    <div>Row 1</div>
    <div>Row 2</div>
    <div>Row 3</div>
    <div>Row 4</div>
    <div>Row 5</div>
    <div>Row 6</div>
    <div>Row 7</div>
    <div>Row 8</div>
    <div>Row 9</div>
    <div>Row 10</div>
    <div>Row 11</div>
    <div>Row 12</div>
    <div>Row 13</div>
    <div>Row 14</div>
    <div>Row 15</div>
    <div>Row 16</div>
    <div>Row 17</div>
    <div>Row 18</div>
    <div>Row 19</div>
    <div>Row 20</div>
    <div>Row 21</div>
    <div>Row 22</div>
    <div>Row 23</div>
    <div>Row 24</div>
    <div>Row 25</div>
    <div>Row 26</div>
    <div>Row 27</div>
    <div>Row 28</div>
    <div>Row 29</div>
    <div>Row 30</div>
    <div>Row 31</div>
    <div>Row 32</div>
    <div>Row 33</div>
    <div>Row 34</div>
    <div>Row 35</div>
    <div>Row 36</div>
    <div>Row 37</div>
    <div>Row 38</div>
    <div>Row 39</div>
    <div>Row 40</div>
    <div>Row 41</div>
    <div>Row 42</div>
    <div>Row 43</div>
    <div>Row 44</div>
    <div>Row 45</div>
    <div>Row 46</div>
    <div>Row 47</div>
    <div>Row 48</div>
    <div>Row 49</div>
    <div>Row 50</div>
  </div>
</a>
<a>
  <div>
    <div>Row 1</div>
    <div>Row 2</div>
    <div>Row 3</div>
    <div>Row 4</div>
    <div>Row 5</div>
    <div>Row 6</div>
    <div>Row 7</div>
    <div>Row 8</div>
    <div>Row 9</div>
    <div>Row 10</div>
    <div>Row 11</div>
    <div>Row 12</div>
    <div>Row 13</div>
    <div>Row 14</div>
    <div>Row 15</div>
    <div>Row 16</div>
    <div>Row 17</div>
    <div>Row 18</div>
    <div>Row 19</div>
    <div>Row 20</div>
    <div>Row 21</div>
    <div>Row 22</div>
    <div>Row 23</div>
    <div>Row 24</div>
    <div>Row 25</div>
    <div>Row 26</div>
    <div>Row 27</div>
    <div>Row 28</div>
    <div>Row 29</div>
    <div>Row 30</div>
    <div>Row 31</div>
    <div>Row 32</div>
    <div>Row 33</div>
    <div>Row 34</div>
    <div>Row 35</div>
    <div>Row 36</div>
    <div>Row 37</div>
    <div>Row 38</div>
    <div>Row 39</div>
    <div>Row 40</div>
    <div>Row 41</div>
    <div>Row 42</div>
    <div>Row 43</div>
    <div>Row 44</div>
    <div>Row 45</div>
    <div>Row 46</div>
    <div>Row 47</div>
    <div>Row 48</div>
    <div>Row 49</div>
    <div>Row 50</div>
  </div>
</a>
<!-- Demo HTML: -->
<br clear="all" />
<h3 style="color : red;">&#10008; Broken</h3>
<h3 style="color : red;">&#10008; Broken</h3>
<h3 style="color : green;">&#10004; Works</h3>
```

Removing the `href` fixes the issue. Is this a Firefox bug?

See 3 examples here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bassmanpaul/80sxosjh)

**P.S.** I'm aware that `a` tags are strictly `inline` elements so aren't really meant to have inner `block` elements, but I believe there are scenarios that require this and I'm curious to why this issue is occurring.

Comment: Bummer! Should be a Firefox bug!

Comment: it is not working in chrome, IE,Edge also

Comment: Hmm I may post it to bugzilla then. I've not been able to reproduce it in any other browser pathak :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This appears to be a bug in Firefox

The crux of the issue is that you are showing a scrollbar on a clickable element and Firefox does not handle this in the same way as Chrome and IE.

[Bug 367028](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=367028) has been open for almost 10 years so I don't think this is going to be addressed any time soon.

## Workaround

By rearranging the HTML slightly so that the overflow is applied to a `div` instead the scrollbar will function as expected in Firefox.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Demo CSS */
  background: #ddd;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/* Demo CSS */

h3 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}
h4 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 15px 20px 15px 0px;
}
* {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!-- Demo HTML: -->
<p>
  When a scrollable container is an <code>&lt;a&gt;</code> tag with a <code>href</code> attribute then the scrollbar cannot be selected. Instead the whole container drags. This only occurs in <strong>Firefox</strong>. Edge, Chrome & IE11 seem okay.
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Note: </strong>Using the mouse wheel to scroll still works.
</p>
<h4>href="#"</h4>
<h4>href="javascript:void(0);"</h4>
<h4>No href</h4>
<br clear="all" />
<!-- Buggy HTML: -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <div>Row 1</div>
    <div>Row 2</div>
    <div>Row 3</div>
    <div>Row 4</div>
    <div>Row 5</div>
    <div>Row 6</div>
    <div>Row 7</div>
    <div>Row 8</div>
    <div>Row 9</div>
    <div>Row 10</div>
    <div>Row 11</div>
    <div>Row 12</div>
    <div>Row 13</div>
    <div>Row 14</div>
    <div>Row 15</div>
    <div>Row 16</div>
    <div>Row 17</div>
    <div>Row 18</div>
    <div>Row 19</div>
    <div>Row 20</div>
    <div>Row 21</div>
    <div>Row 22</div>
    <div>Row 23</div>
    <div>Row 24</div>
    <div>Row 25</div>
    <div>Row 26</div>
    <div>Row 27</div>
    <div>Row 28</div>
    <div>Row 29</div>
    <div>Row 30</div>
    <div>Row 31</div>
    <div>Row 32</div>
    <div>Row 33</div>
    <div>Row 34</div>
    <div>Row 35</div>
    <div>Row 36</div>
    <div>Row 37</div>
    <div>Row 38</div>
    <div>Row 39</div>
    <div>Row 40</div>
    <div>Row 41</div>
    <div>Row 42</div>
    <div>Row 43</div>
    <div>Row 44</div>
    <div>Row 45</div>
    <div>Row 46</div>
    <div>Row 47</div>
    <div>Row 48</div>
    <div>Row 49</div>
    <div>Row 50</div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <div>Row 1</div>
    <div>Row 2</div>
    <div>Row 3</div>
    <div>Row 4</div>
    <div>Row 5</div>
    <div>Row 6</div>
    <div>Row 7</div>
    <div>Row 8</div>
    <div>Row 9</div>
    <div>Row 10</div>
    <div>Row 11</div>
    <div>Row 12</div>
    <div>Row 13</div>
    <div>Row 14</div>
    <div>Row 15</div>
    <div>Row 16</div>
    <div>Row 17</div>
    <div>Row 18</div>
    <div>Row 19</div>
    <div>Row 20</div>
    <div>Row 21</div>
    <div>Row 22</div>
    <div>Row 23</div>
    <div>Row 24</div>
    <div>Row 25</div>
    <div>Row 26</div>
    <div>Row 27</div>
    <div>Row 28</div>
    <div>Row 29</div>
    <div>Row 30</div>
    <div>Row 31</div>
    <div>Row 32</div>
    <div>Row 33</div>
    <div>Row 34</div>
    <div>Row 35</div>
    <div>Row 36</div>
    <div>Row 37</div>
    <div>Row 38</div>
    <div>Row 39</div>
    <div>Row 40</div>
    <div>Row 41</div>
    <div>Row 42</div>
    <div>Row 43</div>
    <div>Row 44</div>
    <div>Row 45</div>
    <div>Row 46</div>
    <div>Row 47</div>
    <div>Row 48</div>
    <div>Row 49</div>
    <div>Row 50</div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a>
    <div>Row 1</div>
    <div>Row 2</div>
    <div>Row 3</div>
    <div>Row 4</div>
    <div>Row 5</div>
    <div>Row 6</div>
    <div>Row 7</div>
    <div>Row 8</div>
    <div>Row 9</div>
    <div>Row 10</div>
    <div>Row 11</div>
    <div>Row 12</div>
    <div>Row 13</div>
    <div>Row 14</div>
    <div>Row 15</div>
    <div>Row 16</div>
    <div>Row 17</div>
    <div>Row 18</div>
    <div>Row 19</div>
    <div>Row 20</div>
    <div>Row 21</div>
    <div>Row 22</div>
    <div>Row 23</div>
    <div>Row 24</div>
    <div>Row 25</div>
    <div>Row 26</div>
    <div>Row 27</div>
    <div>Row 28</div>
    <div>Row 29</div>
    <div>Row 30</div>
    <div>Row 31</div>
    <div>Row 32</div>
    <div>Row 33</div>
    <div>Row 34</div>
    <div>Row 35</div>
    <div>Row 36</div>
    <div>Row 37</div>
    <div>Row 38</div>
    <div>Row 39</div>
    <div>Row 40</div>
    <div>Row 41</div>
    <div>Row 42</div>
    <div>Row 43</div>
    <div>Row 44</div>
    <div>Row 45</div>
    <div>Row 46</div>
    <div>Row 47</div>
    <div>Row 48</div>
    <div>Row 49</div>
    <div>Row 50</div>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- Demo HTML: -->
<br clear="all" />
<h3 style="color : red;">&#10008; Broken</h3>
<h3 style="color : red;">&#10008; Broken</h3>
<h3 style="color : green;">&#10004; Works</h3>
```

Comment: Wow 10 years :s Nice bug find. Similar to your suggestion I chose to swap out the anchor tag in the end.